# generate create table from existing table

Tags: sql, oracle

I have a few large tables in a oracle DB (lots of columns and data types) that I need to move to another oracle database (say from my DEV region to UAT region).  Is there anyway I can get sql developer or sql plus to output a create table statement that is exactly the structure of the existing table?

thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you are making use of the SQL Developer you can right click the table that you want to generate a script for.

From there select Quick DDL and then click on Save To File. This will then generate the create table script to an external sql file. You can do this for multiple tables as well by selecting more than one table at a time.

Hope this helps!!

Answer (score 2):

If you want to get it through SQL statement then you can try the below query

```
SELECT dbms_metadata.get_ddl('TABLE', 'Your_Table_Name') FROM dual;
```

See [DBMS_METADATA](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/B19306_01/appdev.102/b14258/d_metada.htm) for more information.

You can generate the script using Toad software as well (In case you have Toad installed)

Answer (score 0):

Another option is to create a database link between the two schemas and then do a

```
create table table_name AS SELECT * from table_name@original_server
```